# glReadPixels color sequence

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have encountered a problem using glReadPixels in Android platform.

When I specify the internalformat to be GL_RGBA, it fills the buffer with BGRA
if I specify the internalformat to GL_ARGB, it fills the buffer with RGBA.

It happens in one of my Sony Ericsson devices, but in the other devices, glReadPixels works properly.
Is there any other parameter I can get from the device to control the pixel bytes sequence?